# Fastest way to transfer a file from GCS to GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a 1TB file and I'm looking to find the fastest way to transfer that from a GCS storage bucket in the same region as a GCE instance. I've tried using `gsutil` and a few other console utils, but I don't seem to get that fast of transfers between the two (it seems like it's similar to a curl command in that it uses the public internet I believe). It is a large machine, with ~100GB or more of memory.

What is the suggested way to transfer a file **in the fastest way possible** ? It seems like https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers might be relevant but I'm getting a little bit lost in all the possible 'solutions' to this issue.

From [This blog post](https://medium.com/@duhroach/gcs-read-performance-of-large-files-bd53cfca4410), the fastest I was able to get it was:

```
david@instance-2:~$ time gsutil -o 'GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1' 
                                -o 'GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=8' \
                                cp gs://gcp-files/Sales20M.csv .
Copying gs://gcp-files/Sales20M.csv...
/ [1 files][  1.1 GiB/  1.1 GiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/1.1 GiB.

real    0m4.559s
user    0m10.787s
sys     0m5.527s
```

That seems pretty good to be -- about 5s for a 1GB file, so a bit more than 1 Gb/s. Is this the ceiling do you think, or are there any other ways that might be possible to speed this up?

Comment: What size GCE instance? The larger the instance the higher the network bandwidth (2 Gbit per core). `gsutil` is a Python program, write a program that downloads in parallel. Your question uses lots of statements like "fastest", "large', etc. To get a good answer use actual facts, what your goal is and what you are willing to do to achieve that goal (write a program, purchase tools, only use freeware, ...).

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried with both 4.8TB machine (one of the ultra-memory machines) and a 100GB machine and they performed about the same: https://imgur.com/a/QHzfzD9

Answer (score 2):

Network ingress from private addresses is not limited in any way, so other than that you are probably capped by persistent disk throughput (since you are moving a large file). Based on what you wrote the only thing that comes to mind that you should check is the size of your persistent disk. According to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#performance_factors your persistent disk needs to be at least 4TB to achieve maximum write throughput (400MB/s) when using HDDs or 1667GB to achieve 800MB/s when using SSDs.